# React: How to animate removal of a DOM element?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have a banner my React component, to which I want to add "dismiss" capability.  The current implementation looks like:

```
function Home() {
  return(
    <Banner />
    <Main />
  );
}

function Banner() {
  const [hide, setHide] = React.useState(false);
  const handleClick = () => setHide(true);
  return !hide ? (
    <div>
      This is a banner.
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Dismiss</button>
    </div> : null;
}
```

However, this implementation is rather abrupt and I can't animate it.  Is there a better way to avoid jumping of the elements to provide a better UI?

Comment: Instead of completely removes it, why not hide it though css?

Comment: @HaoWu The component is really not required after dismissal, so it has no use there.  That is the hacky solution that I know of -- but I want to know what is the proper way of doing it.

Comment: First you have to animate the size or opacity and then simply remove it AFTER that animation. You can't animate the `display` property so shrinking it to zero size first and then removing it would be the eimplest method.

Comment: Will there also have to be an animation when it is shown?

Comment: @RichardHunter No, it is not mandatory.

Answer (score 6):

My preferred choice for React animations is the react-transition-group library. (There are of course other options).
[Here is my Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/banner-dismiss-demo?file=src/style.css)

It's fairly easy to use. You wrap the component you want to animate in the `CSSTransition` component, add some config properties, and set your styles in a style sheet. One slight gotcha is that the timeout property has to be the same value as the transition times in the stylesheets. See [documentation](https://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/css-transition) for more information.

Here is the most relevant code from the demo:

#### App Component

```
export function App() {
  const [showBanner, setShowBanner] = useState(true);
  const hideBannerHandler = () => setShowBanner(false);
  const showBannerHandler = () => setShowBanner(true);

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={showBannerHandler}>show banner</button>
      <CSSTransition
        in={showBanner}
        timeout={{
          enter: 0,
          exit: 2000
        }}
        unmountOnExit
        classNames="my-node"
      >
        <Banner hideBannerHandler={hideBannerHandler} />
      </CSSTransition>
    </div>
  );
}
```

#### CSS (fragment)

```
.my-node-exit {
  opacity: 1;
}

.my-node-exit-active {
  animation: foo 2s ease forwards;
  transform-origin: left;
}

@keyframes foo {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
    background: pink;
    transform: translate(0, 0);
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px 3px pink;
    color: red;
  }

  50% {
    transform: scale(2);
    background: coral;
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px 3px coral;
    color: limegreen;
  }

  to {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(1);
    background: white;
    color: white;
  }
}
```